# Oracle - large table with large IN

Tags: oracle, optimization, select

Table students has about 10 million records; ID is indexed.
Student grades has 20 million records - student_id is indexed.
I am querying about 20,000 students by their ids ids with a join between students and parents:

```
select * from students s left join grades g on s.id=g.student_id 
where (s.id IN (s1, s2... s1000)
or (s.id IN (s1001, s1002... s2000)
or (s.id IN (s.2001, s2002...s3000) 
//until s20000)
```

I need to split the INs into multiple batches as IN can only get 1000 or less values.

The query takes about 5 minutes to return. Is there any way I can optimize it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do the IDs come from in the first place? Do they come from another query in the same database or an external source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Data Comes from External Source

The `IN` clause is limited to 1000 values.  Don't use it for such searches.

Workaround:

- Use a GTT (Global Temporary Table)
- insert "values of interest" into that GTT
- Modify the `SELECT` statement to `JOIN` against the GTT.

## Example

Create the GTT

```
create global temporary table students_gtt (
  student_id int primary key
);
```

Insert values into the GTT

```
insert into students_gtt
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 50000;
```

and JOIN it in the SELECT statement

```
select
    *
from
    students       s
    left join grades         g on s.id = g.student_id
    join students_gtt   g on s.student_id = g.student_id
```

## Notes

1. First, I suspect a good portion of your time is spent Hard Parsing your query.

   - I'm taking a 22,974,957 row table and left outer joining it to a 93,501,293 row table in addition to joining the 50,000 row GTT.  The values return in seconds.
2. Eventually, you are going to a run into a "node" limit for the parser.
3. The GTT method does not require you to "hack your SQL statement".

## Data from another SQL Statement?

Just include that SQL within the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: What do you mean to join against the GTT. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Also, why will that be faster. How is querying a separate table to get a list of IDs faster the explicitly giving the list of ids..?

Comment: @danielb - I added example and notes.  Referencing Phil(tm)'s comment, the Source of the Student IDs is important for the proper solution.